# CSS background image does not display on first load?

Tags: html, css, background-image

The background image in this html script: `http://themes.googleusercontent.com/image?id=1nCEFJnjbEM1e6XClO-Dh7L-U6FJQuxivkV20FpXYmkNyRA0vQIZPfjuIp6hcROwwArvQ` does not load. But if this image is first opened in the same browser, transferring it into the cache, then the background image is correctly displayed.

HTML follows:

```
<html>
      <head>
            <style type="text/css">
        body {
        font: normal normal 18px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
        color: #000000;
        background: #000002 url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/image?id=1nCEFJnjbEM1e6XClO-Dh7L-U6FJQuxivkV20FpXYmkNyRA0vQIZPfjuIp6hcROwwArvQ) no-repeat fixed top center;
        }
        </style>


      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The problem may look trivial but it is replicated on at least 3 browsers: IE, Firefox, Chrome: no image pre-loaded, no background image displayed. If anyone has the solution to this outwardly quite simple problem, it will be most helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Loaded fine for me. Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: IE, Chrome, Firefox. Tested on two different PCs. Image URL opens fine.

Comment: It's loading perfectly fine for me in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE.

Comment: Probably you loaded image using url and then tried loading this html. In that case it loads fine.

Comment: it's commented out?  You have a comment that wraps around that style.

Comment: @TasawerKhan Your problem is elsewhere. Four different browser's dont' share the same cache. It loaded fine in all. Try replacing the background image with a local image. See if it behaves any differently.

Comment: In every browser I have to load image using url first. Trying to find out where the problem is

Comment: I don't mean on the background line, I mean the <!-- --> that is wrapped around everything

Comment: @JonathanSampson In case of local image it loads fine

Comment: @StefanH It can't be the problem. In case of local image it loads fine

Comment: code updated. I have removed comments

Comment: Is it resolved? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem is with body without content.

Comment: Tried it with and without content. Content has been removed to simplify question

Answer (score 1):

Your image is 1800x1713 - depending on your network connection, it could take some time to download.  You noticed that once it was in your browser's cache, it worked just fine, which makes sense if it is, in fact, the network.

Regarding the image itself, are you sure you have the rights to use it in the first place? The fact that you're pulling it out of the Google cache and that a reverse image search turns up quite a few results is not a good sign.  Make sure you aren't violating the copyright of any images you do use on your site.

Comment: I am afraid it is not the case. I am using a very high speed internet connection and we gave enough time to load image